# python - Regex to match patterns from last

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am stuck in extracting data,

```
import re
s = "this is the [[sample1]] string [[sample2]](explanation)"
re.findall("(?=\[\[)(.*)(?<=\))",s)
```

this results : `['[[sample1]] string [[sample2]](explanation)']`

but i want to extract :  `[[sample2]](explanation)']`

Kindly suggest a way to do this.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can `sample2` contain `[` or `]`? Can `explanation` contain `(` or `)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression is also likely to work:

```
(\[\[[^\]]*\]\]\([^)]*\))
```

#### Test with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"(\[\[[^\]]*\]\]\([^)]*\))"

test_str = """

this is the [[sample1]] string [[sample1]](explanation) this is the [[sample1]] string 

[[sample2]](explanation1) [[]]()

[[sample3]](explanation1) [[sample4]]()

"""


print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.M))
```

#### Output

```
['[[sample1]](explanation)', '[[sample2]](explanation1)', '[[]]()', '[[sample3]](explanation1)', '[[sample4]]()']
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/GZbgSV/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/GZbgSV/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways:

```
import re

s = "this is the [[sample1]] string [[sample2]](explanation)"
res = re.findall(r"\[\[[^(\[]+\([^()]+\)", s)
print(res)
```

The output:

```
['[[sample2]](explanation)']
```

Answer (score 0):

Not regex but:

```py
s = "this is the [[sample1]] string [[sample2]](explanation)"
extract = (s[::-1] [ s[::-1].index(")noitanalpxe(") : s[::-1].index("[[") + 2 ])[::-1]
```